Uses of perlite dust
At the bottom of my bag of perlite, there is lots of white powdery perlite dust. Are there any practical uses of perlite dust in gardening? Is the white powder beneficial as a soil amendment? If there are no beneficial uses, I might dispose the perlite dust by putting it into the trash.

"it depends". It should have some nutrients, but mostly it is silica (so sand), so it depends on what soil do you have and how small are the particle of dust. For sure there are many case it can improve soil, but it depends.

I think there'd be minimal to no effect as a soil amendment. I strongly recommend that you use a facemask while working with it. You do NOT want to breath silica dust.

You might want to consult this thread. My reading: confirms both above comments. Personal guess: probably hazardous on clay-heavy soils because of the small particle size.

I can't think of any gardening use for fine perlite dust past mixing it in the soil for whatever drainage/aeration benefit may remain.  Other than its mechanical properties, perlite is more or less glass.  Pretty darn inert.  Here is another question talking about that part: Recycling potting mix with perlite: Would I get garden soil with perlite dust?
Perlite does have other uses, although I'm not sure if they apply on this scale.

Filtration
Construction
Industry
Insulation
Animal Husbandry

Do you keep chickens?  Or filter things very often?
